# PHP regular expression : match the closest one

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I have a string like this

```
<div><span style="">toto</span> some character <span>toto2</span></div>
```

My regex:

```
/(<span .*>)(.*)(<\/span>)/
```

I used preg_match and it returns the entire string

```
<span style="">toto</span> some character <span>toto2</span>
```

I want it returns:

```
<span style="">toto</span>
and
<span>toto2</span>
```

What do I need to do to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php.html for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules.

Comment: @AndyLester A parser is not a magical solution to protect from changes in HTML.

Comment: @AndyLester Using a whole parsing module just to parse a simple <span> tag seems a little too heavy. I don't think any changes could affect this simple case.

Comment: How about the case of `<span style="">\ntoto\n</span>`, for example?  If you're working with a single set of data that will not change, then go ahead and write your code for that specific dataset.  If you're relying on that markup to be presented like that in the future, you're asking for sorrow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
/(<span[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/span>)/
```

Check the docs here at [PHP preg_match Repetition](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php):

> By default, the quantifiers are "greedy", that is, they match as much as possible

and

> However, if a quantifier is followed by a question mark, then it becomes lazy, and instead matches the minimum number of times possible

Comment: Although I test, it works, but not quite understand. Why the "?" isn't after "span" or ">", but after ".*" ?

Comment: Because you want the `.*` to match least chars possible.

Comment: In that case, `/<span.*?\<\/span>/` is enough?

Comment: Yes, `/<span.*?<\/span>/` is enough, if you don't need the groups you created with `()` in your original expression.

Comment: For a simple example like this it works, but I still think this will give an unexpected result if we are trying to match : `<span id="aspan"><span id="child_span"</span></span>`

Comment: You are right. That's why they said "Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML". If you are sure there won't be nesting spans, you can use my solution. If not, then regex may not be the best tool for your need.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I guess all previous answers are correct, I just want to add that as you only want to capture the whole expressions (i.e. from  to ) you don't have to capture eveything inside the regexp with `()`
The following does what you expect without capturing additional expressions

```
/(<span\w*[^>]*>[^<]*<\/span>)/
```

(tested on http://rubular.com/)

EDIT : of course there might be some differences between PHP and ruby regexp implementations, but the idea is the same :)

Comment: [^<]* will not match other elements such as <input/>, </b> inside the span tag